# How to notify web-module about job status performing in MDB (EJB3.0)?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss-mdb

We are using Message Driven Bean to generate large reports and process durable tasks. How can MDB notify web-module f.e. session listener about job status without client poll?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create web service in EJB and use it, but it PERMGENious!!!

Comment: Can you explain your answer in depth?

Answer (score 0):

Yeee, PermGen is eternal problem, good luck.